# gsutil - what are the storage class options for cp?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm using `gsutil` CLI to copy files to buckets of Google Cloud. But I didn't find what are the options for specifying a storage class? I read the documentation and the options are not written there. It's just written to use `-s <class>` but what are the options for `<class>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the following [Storage Class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#classes) that you can define:

[STANDARD](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#standard) 
[NEARLINE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#nearline) 
[COLDLINE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#coldline) 
[ARCHIVE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#archive)

Additional: You should only use `copy` to copy between the same location and storage class